# What does class ClassName < ::OtherClassName do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Yesterday, I found the following code in [RSpec](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/ef449c38a7e98dd276ffb6e37758ef6f38a53801/lib/spec/runner/option_parser.rb#L6):

```
class OptionParser < ::OptionParser
```

What does this do? What is the difference between this and `class OptionParser < NameSpace::OptionParser`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An runnable example might explain the idea best:

```
class C
  def initialize
    puts "At top level"
  end
end

module M
  class C
    def initialize
      puts "In module M"
    end
  end

  class P < C
    def initialize
      super
    end
  end

  class Q < ::C
    def initialize
      super
    end
  end
end

M::P.new
M::Q.new
```

Produces when run:

```
In module M
At top level
```

Comment: Thank you. 

Just let me confirm if my understanding is correct. Is OptionParser refer to OptionParser in the standard library called optparse in my example?

Comment: Exactly. In your example `::OptionParser` refers to the standard library class

Comment: Your example is good in terms of "runnability" but too scarce for a newbie :)